# How do I get the information from a meta tag with Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am new to dojo and am trying to get the information from a meta tag that looks like this:

```
<meta content="Page101" scheme="SubjectTaxonomy" name="DC.Subject">
```

How do I get the "Page101" information?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question. Do you _need_ to use Dojo for this? Because it can be done with native JavaScript. `document.getElementsByTagName("meta")` will return [an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that you can use to extract information from.

Comment: Yes I have to use dojo for this. Is this possible with dojo?
There are 18 meta tags in my page and I need to the content from this tag

Comment: Absolutely you can, I posted an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [the dojo/query module](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html#dojo-query) or the global `dojo.query` method. To get all `meta` tags and loop through them extracting the content you can do:

```
dojo.query('meta').forEach(function(metaTag){

  var content = metaTag.content;
  // Do something with the content.

});
```

Or if you are looking for a specific `meta` tag with `content="Page101"`, you can restrict the selector like so:

```
dojo.query('meta[content="Page101"]')
```

This will return a NodeList with `meta` tags that match the desired `content` and you can do whatever you need to with them (probably only one).

Comment: Awesome, but now lets say the "Page101" changes from page to page. How do I still get access to this tag? Would the name="DC.Subject" have anything to do there? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to keep a reference to the "Page101" `meta` tag or get a reference to the new tag with "Page[number]"?

Comment: I think I got it. I changed content="Page101" to name="DC.Subject" that returns the information with the meta tag whose name is DC.Subject. Thank you so much. 1/3 way finished with my script. May need additional help. BTW, how did you learn dojo? Any good resources you recommend?

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it. I actually had to learn it at my new job, so I had some help from coworkers who were already well versed in it. Besides that, Dojo provides some really awesome [tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) and [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/index.html) for you to look at. After I got the feel of things I was able to start digging into their [api](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) and now I mostly just look at the source code of their files to figure things out. Hope this helps!